# Is it possible to have PHP create an alias in IIS (Internet Information Services)?

Tags: php, iis, alias, vhosts

Is it possible to have PHP create an alias in IIS (Internet Information Services)?

An example of what I'm trying to achieve using Apache would be using PHP to edit httpd-vhosts.conf and append the following line

```
Alias /test.projectOne "C:/xampp/htdocs/test"
```

However we're not using Apache and it needs to be done in IIS. The idea is that a script can set up its own projects.

From the research that I have done so far, I get the impression that I need to edit the MetaBase.xml and the MBSchema.xml in some way?

Comment: Looks like you can. What you need to do is open IIS and in the properties for your local computer, "Enable Direct Metabase Edit". 
This "Allows you to edit the IIS metabase configuration file while IIS is running".
You then edit the Metabase.xml with the relevant virtual directory details.

Comment: Can you do it using command-line tools? If so maybe you can do it through `exec` or similar?

Comment: Good idea Svish. I have been able to create the vhost using the following code:    c:\windows\system32\iisvdir.vbs /create W3SVC/1/ROOT test123 C:\webserver\Apache2.2\htdocs\test' but exec is not working for me so I have been unable to test it using PHP. I've posted a different thread in relation to my exec issue.

Comment: Looks like you can't use the exec() function with IIS. So I'm going to run a scheduled task to run the script through the cmd which should do the trick. exec seems to work fine from the command prompt

Comment: Probably some security settings or something then. But good to hear you found a solution :)